# Windows 10 blinking and switching the active windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot-camp

I have a problem with Windows 10 it is happening a few weeks after installation date. Here is my screen capture on that problem http://sendvid.com/nbrvn44w
It is seams to be common problem https://www.google.com.au/search?q=windows+10+blinking+screen not sure if my is different. 
Also sometimes it is just making some windows on top of others and I have to close it.

I tried a solution like disabling the `Problem Reports and Solutions Control Panel Support` and `Windows Error Reporting Service` Services through `msconfig` but didn't help.

Also I reinstalled the `bootcamp` drivers but didn't help either.

Any ideas how can I solve that problem?

UPDATE:
Non MS services I've got running:
[image]

- Disabled all non MS services with `msconfig`- no help.
- Using ccleaner just disabled all startup programs, tasks and context menu items but after restart still all the same.

Comment: in msconfig did you try hiding all microsoft services and then disable all? and disabled all start up programs?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin just two I mentioned above. I might try to disable them+startup programs and then give you an update.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Search
Type **msconfig** in the search box, and then click **msconfig**.

On the **Services tab** of the System Configuration dialog box, select the **Hide** all Microsoft services check box, and then go to **Disable all**.

On the Startup tab of the **System Configuration dialog box**, tap or click Open **Task Manager.**

On the **Startup tab** in Task Manager, for each startup item, select the item and then click Disable.

**Close Task Manager.**

On the Startup tab of the **System Configuration dialog box**, click **OK**, and then **restart** the computer.

Try this ive read some reports of it fixing the issue.

Comment: Yeah I come across this but never tried. So just tried now and no luck...

Comment: Also just using ccleaner disabled all startup programs, etc and after restart still all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HP computer with HP Simplepass (biometric security for login) try disabling all features except login. For some reason, it sometimes fails to launch in the task bar in windows 10, and it keeps trying to initialize and failing, which causes this issue.

If you do not have an HP or similar program--look for something like this. The issue is likely being caused by an incompatible program or service trying to automatically launch upon login.