# Disabling the flashing title bar when clicking outside a focused window on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, accessibility

Edit: I have checked for duplicates. There is no post on this website or on Google that matches my problem. Try it for yourself, it's a Windows feature and **not** a bug or an error. I have tried various machines, running win7 and win10, and they *all* exhibit the same flashing window when you click outside of its active area.

Edit 2: Happens in any program. Windows Settings, Illustrator, you name it.
As long as it is a *focused window that requires confirmation before being able to close*.
It is *not* always blinking, only when you click outside of the window.

**Description:**
In Windows 10, while in a focused window that require confirmation before being closed, clicking outside the window causes the title bar of the window to rapidly flash with a high contrast color a few times, to warn the user that there's still a window open.

Is there a way to disable this flashing behavior? I don't mind having a window open that requires confirmation to close, I just really don't like the flashing title bar effect.

I have deliberately not embedded this image since it contains flashing imagery. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X97VW.gif

I think this is particularly annoying and should maybe just flash once, or, warn the user in another, less intrusive way. Or, at least provide a setting to disable the effect. I'm aware it's *meant* to draw attention, it just seems a bit overkill for the problem at hand.
It might also be an issue to users with photosensitive epilepsy.

**What I've tried:**
There is a setting under Ease of Access related to "Show audio alerts visually" but that is toggled off and likely does not affect the title bar flashing.
I've looked through Settings and was unable to find any option related to title bar flashing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 blinking and switching the active windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1034575/windows-10-blinking-and-switching-the-active-windows)

Comment: Try to boot in Safe Boot to exclude a problem with Windows itself.

Comment: @CaldeiraG It does not answer my question, and this isn't a bug or an error in Windows. It's a Windows feature. It's not switching screens, only _visually_ blinking. See the attached image for reference. Edit: I've checked other PCs running various versions of Windows (7 and 10) and they all exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Is the behaviour specific to one program or not?

Comment: @CaldeiraG No, it happens in any program / Windows Settings, it just has to be a window that's focused and requires confirmation(so OK / Cancel / Apply) before being closed. I urge you to try this yourself; is this different on your system?

Comment: It only flashes if you click in it's owner window showing you have a modal open in that app. Flashing replaced beeping.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I'd really like to turn off the flashing though. I'm easily distracted and something flashing like that just throws me off completely.

Comment: So how should Windows give feedback that you've clicked where it means nothing. It doesn't flash if you are activating the app. It is also separate to flashing apps that are in the background and want user attention.

Comment: I'm probably not qualified on what an alternative solution would be, all I'm asking is if there's a way to disable this.

Comment: Is that image a mock up, or a capture of what is actually happening? I'm very familiar with windows flashing to get attention, but in no case, no UI highlight color combinations, did it ever flash as harshly. This is default Windows behavior, but there is something unique to your computer which is presenting this normally subtle flash as such a harsh flash.

Comment: @music2myear This is a screen recording, actual behavior. It's a fairly fresh installation of Windows 10 Home edition, few months old. Not running any plugins or tools that may change interface behavior. l've only changed the interface color to a color that's easy on my eyes, in this case dark theme + brown headers.